# How to configure endpoints and esp to publish gRPC with enabled ServerReflection feature

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-kubernetes-engine

I created a simple gRPC API service, published it using GKE-ESP-endpoints. It works. Now I would like to publish the service with `ServerReflection` feature. Reflection has been added into the gRPC server and when some grpc client, for instance `grpcurl`, directly sends `list` request to the server, the server returns the correct answer with the list of accessible gRPC services:

```
$ grpcurl --plaintext localhost:8000 list
grservices.diagnostic
```

When the same request is sent to public ip of load-balancer the answer is `Failed to list services: rpc error: code = NotFound desc = Method does not exist.`

Logs of esp:

```
"POST /grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo HTTP/2.0" 404 0 "-" "grpc-go/1.14.0-dev"
```

Logs of endpoints:

```
Endpoints management skipped for an unrecognized HTTP call: POST /grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo
```

For me it looks the reason is in because `endpoints` don't know about `grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection` service and don't allow routing the request to gRPC container. I reviewed all examples that I can googled and didn't see any changes between `api-config.yaml` files for gRPC with enabled `ServerReflection` and without `ServerReflection`.

I have tried to change `api_config.yaml` and apply it for the deployment with no success unfortunately, because I should have descriptor {{.pb}} file for {{grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection}}.

So my question is how to configure endpoints and esp to provide `reflection`?

Thanks a lot for any ideas and proposals.

api_config.yaml:

```
type: google.api.Service
config_version: 3

#
# Name of the service configuration.
#
name: diagnostic.endpoints.[id-project].cloud.goog

#
# API title to appear in the user interface (Google Cloud Console).
#
title: diagnostic gRPC API
apis:
- name: grservices.diagnostic
# -name: grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection

#
# API usage restrictions.
#
#usage:
#  rules:
#  # Diagnostic methods can be called without an API Key.
#  - selector: grservices.diagnostic.GetDateTime
#    allow_unregistered_calls: true
#
#  - selector: grservices.diagnostic.GetTimeZones
#    allow_unregistered_calls: true
#
##  - selector: grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection.ServerReflectionInfo
##    allow_unregistered_calls: true

usage:
  rules:
  # Allow unregistered calls for all methods.
  - selector: "*"
    allow_unregistered_calls: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple. I just downloaded `reflection.proto` and compiled the new `.pb` file using `reflection.proto` and my own `proto` file of my services:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grpc/grpc/master/src/proto/grpc/reflection/v1alpha/reflection.proto

python -m grpc.tools.protoc --include_imports --include_source_info --proto_path=.  --proto_path="../googleapis" --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. --descriptor_set_out=api_descriptor.pb reflection.proto diagnostic.proto

# delete _pb2.py files of reflection. The files are already presented in virtenv as the part of grpcio-reflection package
rm reflection_pb2.py
rm reflection_pb2_gprc.py

# upload the new config to endpoints
gcloud endpoints services deploy api_descriptor.pb api_config.yaml
```

Testing:

```
$ grpcurl -insecure ${EXT_IP}:443 list                      
grservices.diagnostic

$ grpcurl -insecure ${EXT_IP}:443 list grservices.diagnostic
GetDateTime
GetTimeZones

grpcurl -insecure ${EXT_IP}:443 grservices.diagnostic.GetDateTime
{
  "datetime": "2018-07-23 17:21:16"
}

$ grpcurl -insecure ${EXT_IP}:443 grservices.diagnostic/GetdateTime

$ grpcurl -d '{"time_zone": "Israel"}' -insecure ${EXT_IP}:443 grservices.diagnostic.GetDateTime
{
  "datetime": "2018-07-23 20:25:41Z+0300"
}
```

The changed part of `api_config.yaml` file:

```
apis:
- name: grservices.diagnostic
- name: grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser expects the HTTP response to contain valid CORS headers. But The backend is gRPC, it could not handle CORS.

You can find your solution [Here](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp/issues/322)

Comment: @Alioula, the browser haven't been used to test `gRPC` reflection. Anyway the service works well with browsers and `http1.1` with no issues.